# PHP—Chrome adds space between <label> and <span>

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, firefox, label

With Chrome, the browser adds a tiny space between the `<label>` and `<span>`, but only on some of the labels.

[Chrome - Normal Label (Player 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M94Gx.png)

[Chrome - With Space (Player 7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbUlt.png)

With Mozilla Firefox, the browser does NOT render this behavior.

[Firefox - Normal Label (Player 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrqgV.png)

[Firefox - Normal Label (Player 7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wQFN.png)

I'm using `<label>` and `<span>` to differentiate the colors between PLAYER—# and the Player's Name.

Both of these examples are coded the same way, and both of these methods produce the same results:

1)

```
<div class="card card-header rounded-0 pl-2 py-1">
  <label class="players text-uppercase mb-0" for="player_7_text">PLAYER 7&mdash;(<span class='text-white'><?php echo $player_7_title ?></span>)</label>
</div><!-- card-header -->
```

2)

```
  // From PHP File
  $player_7_title = "PLAYER 7&mdash;(<span class='text-white'>" .  $row_players['player_7'] . "</span>)";

<div class="card card-header rounded-0 pl-2 py-1">
  <label class="players text-uppercase mb-0" for="player_7_text"><?php echo $player_7_title ?></label>
</div><!-- card-header -->
```

I checked the database entries for any extra spaces. I reviewed my HTML, including the Inspector Tool. I also tinkered with the PHP concatenation operators. No spaces.

EDIT: I believe it has something to do with the em dash entity `&mdash;`. I switched the em dash for the en dash `&ndash;`, which fixes the issue. However, I would like to use `&mdash;`

Comment: Certainly you _will_ be able to spot what style rule exactly is resposible for the difference. That might well be a rule built into the browser engines which would indicate that you do not propperly reset those.

Comment: Why do you think that this is related to PHP?

Comment: @NicoHaase It may or may not be related to PHP. I'm just not sure. Removing the <span> fixes the issue, but I can no longer style the player's name to another color.